# How to define jwt configuration in jhipster?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, microservices, gateway

I have two microservices, The first one is a web API, the another is a gateway.
I've already started both, but I cannot authenticate with no user. Neither admin or user.

When I try to log in, I receive this message on API server.

> **InsufficientAuthenticationException**: Full authentication is required
>   to access this resource 2018-02-23 13:05:31.373  WARN 7144 --- [ 
>   XNIO-2 task-3] o.z.p.spring.web.advice.AdviceTrait      :
>   Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource

Both microservices are with the default configuration of jhipster .
The gateway was created with --skip-server option.

I believe the problem is the server_api_url  because all the calls to api is directed to port 9000 but the api is running on 8081.

I got this from Chrome Dev tools:
Request URL:http://localhost:9000/api/profile-info?cacheBuster=1519408025933

The **:9000** is wrong the port must be 8081.
Where can I change that ?.

I have already change the  webpack.common.js

> SERVER_API_URL: `'http://localhost:8081/'`

But nothing work.

Comment: A gateway is not a microservice. If you have skipped server when generating it, how can it be a gateway knowing that the main feature of a gateway is to be a reverse proxy using Zuul? Skipping client would makes sne, skipping server does not. What are you trying to do? This is really confusing.

Comment: Sorry. I really got the mean of the gateway application wrong.
I just want to  have two applications: an API  e and Front-end project. And I don't Know which is the best way to do that. Acually I have an API and a front end application( this was the application that I skipped the server). I want that all autenticate and actions of the front-end application must be processed in the API . I don't know where to configure the base of this API_URL

Comment: Still your architecture is unclear to me. It looks like a monolith but with separated client like http://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/ What is your goal? I can't help you if you don't describe the reason why you are complexifying things.

Comment: Yeah, My goal is a separate front-end and api.  For example to do the autenticate I just need to change the url in auth methods in angular?

Comment: It's not that simple, you may have to deal with CORS depending on how you want to serve angular bundle. Your deployment architecture is still not clear to me and also the reason why you want this complexity.

Comment: Here I have the API(A microservice application without client side). https://github.com/felipe-rodrigues/SEP-API
Now I want an front-end application that uses this and others API..
Which is the best way to do that? An Gateway application, or a monolith.

Comment: Sorry If I'm making it hard. It's because I don't how to build this kind of application . And I'm looking for the right way to do.

Comment: Well if you are new to this, start by a monolith and evolve later on when you can afford the extra complexity of a microservices architecture (gateway, registry, elk,  ..) and when you can split up your domain into bounded contexts (use DDD). For chat like this use gitter https://gitter.im/jhipster/generator-jhipster

Comment: I got it. But May I separate the front-end of a monolith application?

Comment: But frontend and backend are separated in a JHipster monolith: frontend in javascript executes in browser and backend in java executes on server. It's very different from classic PHP or ASP.net apps where frontend code is also executed/rendered on server. What kind of separation do you want to achieve?